# IE8 CSS rendering issue (table)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've got quite common IE8 issue with my site. IE8 renders my page differently than other browsers, which is quite annoying. I'd love if someone could help, please!

I've tried to give IE8 its own stylesheet but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the page with the issue:

http://www.routeqr.com/toimex/tuotteet

Scroll down to picture section and you'll see that the first colum and the second column got too much space between them.

The TH-tags are also rendered wrong.

IE doesn't render margins properly there, just check the same page with Firefox or with other browser and you should see the difference.

I'd appreciate it a lot if someone could help me, I'm so lost myself.

HTML-code

```
<table class="tuotekuvat">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><a name="kannakkeet">&raquo; Kannakkeet</a></th>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.custom .tuotekuvat th {
float: left;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you're trying to give IE its own stylesheet? What do you mean when you say it's not working? The stylesheet isn't loading, or the styles aren't doing what you expect?

Comment: Try opening the webpage in IE8 or IE9, and the problem becomes clear. The table cells are being rendered larger for the first column.

Comment: I don't have IE, I'm on a Mac, and the point is, he should be posting some code -- not a go look at my web site and tell me what's wrong kind of question.

Comment: You'll get more help if you post code instead of a question that merely points to your Web site and asks us to figure out what's wrong with it. See this question, that was closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596603/my-layout-is-not-working-properly

Comment: Thesis Theme for WordPress automatically gives IE8 its own CSS-file, but who do I know if IE actually uses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is not coded correctly, you have one `th` (cell) with no `colspans` specified, and in the `table` itself some rows have 6 cells (columns) and some have 5. any browser may have trouble evening that up ;)

Then you are floating the single `th` - IE 7 and below don't understand float on a table cell/header element and will be forcing the whole of the 1st column to be as wide as the header link

If I can suggest you stick to one method or another, either floating a header outside the table, or even putting it in it's own `<thead>` element  - and then using `table-layout: fixed` on the entire table so that the columns are forced to be of equal width. that should help even it up.. but mainly if you decide that the table is to have six columns (whether all of them are used or not) then for example that single `th` should be `<th colspan="6">`

get the table HTML right first and the rest should perfectly OK across browser if you then want to make it look like there's gaps between table rows and table headings you can pad the `th`.. but I don't really see a need for it to float outside the table structure

Comment: Thanks clairesuzy, I had the table really messed up :) By the way is it valid coding if there are empty <td> cells in a table?

Comment: @Juuso - no worries! Did you get it rendering similarly across browser yet, repost code (edit the question to add it)  if you're still having  issues now - and Yes, empty cells are valid :)

Comment: Just be aware that truly empty table cell often won't render properly in IE, especially if you have styling on the cell (as opposed to the row, for example). Try putting a non-breaking space (&nbsp;) into the cell to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left and right padding:
`padding: 10px;`
becomes
`padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;`

Hope this helps!

N.S.

Comment: Hey Nathan, that would have been one solution also, thanks for insight :) I changed TH colspan="6" which seems to be quite good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to empty `<td>` cells. It used to be that you needed at least an `&nbsp;` to have it render properly across browsers. I think that may no longer be case with current versions.

As an aside, I would recommend using tools like [firefox webdeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) . Webdeveloper has a plethora of nice features along with a link to the [w3c Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) which has helped me find malformed html.